# Clion подключил MinGv, но всё равно не хочет компилировать код

Tags: c++, clion

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде бы клион нашёл mingv, как это видно на картинке, но при этом запустить код всё равно не удаётся. Кнопка run не работает.

Comment: начнем с того, что использовать кириллические символы в путях в винде, где это может запускаться в консоли, немного опрометчиво. Лучше использовать простые пути с латиницей и без пробелов. А также, clion - это простая программа. Она не может просто так взять и запустить Ваше приложение, так как просто не знает, как это сделать. Вам нужно предоставить cmake/make файл.